# Fixed DC voltage output on variable supply

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-to-dc

I have 3 small solar panels rated 6 volt  200ma, joined in series. Voltage received from these panels varies from 0 to 17 volts depending upon light source. I need fixed output of 5 volt all the time, I searched Google and found step up and down converters but couldn't found a device that can do both at a time. Is there a way to achieve fixed voltage on variable DC supply?

Comment: You should search for "buck-boost" converters.